# right alignment of button using css

Tags: html, css

#### style sheet code:

```
<style type="text/css">`
.btn {
float: right;clear: right;height: 17px;margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
}
</style>
```

The below piece of code is inside a fieldset.

```
<span class="btn">
    <span>
        <html:link href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();">
            <span>click me</span>
        </html:link>
    </span>
</span>
```

I want to align the button and text on the right side, but it is only left aligned.

Can you please suggest me.

Comment: Enlighten me, what is a fieldset?

Comment: Is it possible to upload your code to http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can you please provide the complete mark-up and CSS of your form?

Comment: @JohanVandenRym It wasn't visible. Edited.

Comment: Why do u use clear right if u want to align to right? Remove that and see if working.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define position and display.

```
 <style type="text/css">
   .btn {
     display: inline;
     position: relative;
     float: right;
     clear: right;
     height: 17px;
     margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;
     padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
    }
  </style>
```

To position the button at a certain horizontal position from the left margin:

```
 <style type="text/css">
   .btn {
     display: inline;
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     clear: both;
     height: 17px;
     margin: 0 0 0 66%;
     padding: 0 0 30px 0;
   }
 </style>
```

Replace the 66% above with a position of your choice.

If you prefer to use "left: 10px;" to position the button, you'll have to change "position" to "absolute", and "float" and "clear" are useless:

```
 <style type="text/css">
   .btn {
     display: inline;
     position: absolute;
     left: 10px;
     height: 17px;
     margin: 0 0 0 0;
     padding: 0 0 30px 0;
   }
 </style>
```

Comment: How to align little bit on the left side. Now it is on the right side, i need to bring it between the center and right. which parameter i need to modify for this change

Comment: please post the code then i can tell u full. But to alingn left we use Left:10px parameter to change u can search on google for this property.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `text-align: left;` to the `.btn` or to his parent.

Answer (score 0):

This code is work:

html

```
<fildset id="outerBox">
    <span class="btn">
    <span>
        <link href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();">
            <span>click me</span>
        </link>
    </span>
</span>
</fildset>
```

css:

```
.btn {
float: right;clear: right;height: 17px;margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
}
#outerBox {
    width:100%;
}
```

demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/U3K4w/

I believe the problem are in other stylesheet rules.

Enjoy your code!